# display results from a combo box in swt

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I have a combo box with a list of entries and when I choose an entry eg dog I want to display an image of a dog beside the combo box.
Would anybody have any examples of this in swt that I could take a look at?

Ann.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `SelectionListener` to your combo box.

```
    combo.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent event ) {
            // ...
        }
    } );
```

On the `widgetSelected`method, get the selection index - using `combo.getSelectionIndex()` -, map it to your image and display it wherever you want (e.g. on a Label: `label.setImage(image)`).